# will i lose my photos, voice recordings, videos and notes if i reset my samsung galaxy s1

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, samsung, factory-reset, photos

If I reset my Samsung Galaxy S1 to **factory reset mode** will i lose my photos my voice recordings and my notes? 
Because i really need those, but its been so long since i've used this phone and i forgot my password to the account and the only way to delete the account is to reset the phone to factory mode i have another account but it wont let me use it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Depends if you have used memory card and saved it there, in which case they are safe and won't be deleted. it could be the reason why *Ramzy Shah* didn't lose his data, if he had external memory to save all private data on, or used some backup cloud service like *Aravindan* said. 
 I'd rather focus on either recalling your password or looking for a way to recover password, *because once reset, it will erase all the data*.

---

With that said, I think you'll find this guide very useful and **recover your password** :)
[https://www.howtogeek.com/226942/what-to-do-if-you-forget-your-android-phone's-pin-pattern-or-password/](https://www.howtogeek.com/226942/what-to-do-if-you-forget-your-android-phone%E2%80%99s-pin-pattern-or-password/)
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Surely you will lost your personal data, contacts and everything. To avoid this, you should **Backup** your files and everything to your SD Card. You can **Restore** it again to your mobile.

This following site will help you how to take backup and reset your mobile and then restore it back.

http://www.wikihow.com/Reset-a-Galaxy-S

Thats all.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you shouldn't lose any of those, only the settings you've made on the phone and applications you've installed on it. I've reset a phone to the default settings, but it was really long time ago so right now I can't remember in detail what exactly got deleted. However I would suggest you connect your phone to a computer and make a backup of the files you don't want to lose, just in case, but usually you really shouldn't lose any of this files, by resetting it.